# ASP.net drop down list not working in google chrome

Tags: html, asp.net, telerik

I created Aps.net Application in which I am loading reports from database... I am facing a problem with drop down list ... this is working fine in internet explorer but not working in google chrome... 
here is the image of IE :
[image]

here is the image of Chrome...

[image]

the arrow is marking the line which is showing on clicking drop down button... Kindly help me out... here is the HTML code

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlMonths" Width="125" Skin="Vista" runat="server" EmptyMessage="Select Month">
                                                                                        <Items>
                                                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="January" Value="1" />
                                                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="February" Value="2" />
                                                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="March" Value="3" />
                                                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="April" Value="4" />
                                                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="May" Value="5" />
                                                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="June" Value="6" />
                                                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="July" Value="7" />
                                                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="August" Value="8" />
                                                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="September" Value="9" />
                                                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="October" Value="10" />
                                                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="November" Value="11" />
                                                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="December" Value="12" />
                                                                                        </Items>
                                                                                        <CollapseAnimation Type="OutQuint" Duration="200"></CollapseAnimation>
                                                                                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Here is the usage of drop down dialog code:

```
ddlMonths.SelectedValue = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
```

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/forums/not-displaying-correctly-in-chrome

Comment: Your code is working fine in both chrome and IE.

Comment: is the dropdown is wrapped inside some div or panel...

Comment: no this is just showing a line on clicking drop down list

Comment: my code is only woking on IE... the upper image is from IE...in which drop down list is working fine...

Comment: I have tested your code and its working on Win 7 Chrome 43.2357.124m

Comment: the same thing is happening to me with a Telerik RadDropDown control in ASP.NET WebForms. Chrome on both OSX and Win.  All other browsers seem to be be fine.  Did you ever get a resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **EnableOverlay** to **true** for the combo box. My best guess with the available info is that the content below the dropdown is some heavyweight content like a flash or pdf plugin that hides HTML.